# How can std::vector::clear() be called without an instance if it's not static?

Tags: c++

I'm reading this code from [OpenVPN3](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/f1a32af29cd41b62212829d6713198207ed5315c/openvpn/common/options.hpp#L724):

```
class OptionList : public std::vector<Option>, public RCCopyable<thread_unsafe_refcount>
{
  void clear()
  {
    std::vector<Option>::clear();
    map_.clear();
  }
};
```

How is it possible that the class method `clear` calls `std::vector<Option>::clear()`? `std::vector`'s `clear` is a method, not static function. How can it be called without an instance?

Comment: In this context `std::vector<Options>` refers to `*this` base class instance.

Comment: essentially it's `this->std::vector<Option>::clear();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OptionList` derives from `std::vector<Option>`:

https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/f1a32af29cd41b62212829d6713198207ed5315c/openvpn/common/options.hpp#L385

```
  class OptionList : public std::vector<Option>, public RCCopyable<thread_unsafe_refcount>
```

So it's not calling `clear()` without an instance; it's calling the `clear()` function on the parent class. Without indicating `std::vector<Option>::`, it would call the `clear()` function on the derived class, leading to infinite recursion.

Note that `clear()` is not declared `virtual` in `std::vector`, and `OptionList` inherits publicly from `std::vector<Option>`. This is questionable design, because it goes against the Liskov Substitution Principle: you can't use an `OptionList` where `std::vector<Option>` is expected, because the wrong `clear()` will be called, probably violating the expectations of the `OptionList` class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no static method involved here and no call "without object". The class you are looking at is:

```
class OptionList : public std::vector<Option>, public RCCopyable<thread_unsafe_refcount>
```

So the line

```
std::vector<Option>::clear();
```

Calls the member function `clear` of the base class. This is similar to

```
struct base {
    void some_method() {};
};
struct dervied : base {
    void some_method() {           // note: not virtual, hides base method
         base::some_method();      // calls method from base
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an instance, it's `*this`.

`clear` is a member of `OptionList`, which inherits `std::vector<Option>`. The call is qualified because otherwise it would be infinitely recursive